# Pandas: Select columns, default if non-existent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>> df
     val1 val2 val3
key
  1     1    1    1
  2     2    2    2
  3     3    3    3
```

Now I want to select columns `val1`, `val2`, and (here's the kicker:) `val4`

```
>>> df[["val1", "val2", "val4"]]
KeyError: "['val4'] not in index"
```

What I would like:

```
>>> df.something(something)
     val1 val2 val4
key
  1     1    1  NaN
  2     2    2  NaN
  3     3    3  NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC `reindex`

```
df.reindex(columns=["val1", "val2", "val4"])
Out[431]: 
     val1  val2  val4
key                  
1       1     1   NaN
2       2     2   NaN
3       3     3   NaN
```

Also `.loc` can do it , but will raise a  warning  : Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

```
df.loc[:,["val1", "val2", "val4"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], columns=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'])

def check_columns(df, values):

    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in values:
        try:
            temp[i] = df[i]
        except:
            temp[i] = np.nan
    return temp

print(check_columns(df, ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']))
print(check_columns(df, ['val1', 'val2', 'val4']))
```

Gives:

```
   val1  val2  val3
0     1     1     1
1     2     2     2
2     3     3     3
   val1  val2  val4
0     1     1   NaN
1     2     2   NaN
2     3     3   NaN
```